# Morphing a mesh between more than two shapes

Tags: animation, mesh, shape-keys

I want to morph a cube into a sphere, and the sphere into a cone, all in one animation.

Unless I am missing something, shape keys allow objects to go from A to B and back to A, or A to C and back to A, etc.

What is the most natural and efficient way to go from A to B to C?

Comment: Depends on the shape keys activation order. Can start with B set to 1, then B set to zero (so have A) and finally C set to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set Shapekey B to depend on shapekey A, and shapekey C to depend on shapekey B.
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: It works, but: it seems to me that in order to obtain shapes B, C, D, etc, you always start from the original object. Is it possible to *model* each shape starting from the aspect that the previous shape has when its value is 1?

Comment: I don't know of a easy way to do it, maybe someone else knows ?